# How can I make FTP ignore Git Files?

Tags: ftp, git

Is there a way that I can have my FTP client ignore the .git directory?  Is there anything like the .gitignore (.ftpignore) file with FTP?

Comment: That depends on your FTP client. Without knowing, which one you use, nobody can give you an exact answer. However, unlike SVN git uses only one folder, that is also directly in the root of the repository. Its not very difficult to just "not select" it.

Comment: I was really wondering if the FTP protocol had anything like an ignore file.  My assumption is that since FTP is a protocol and not an application it does not.  I am using Cyberduck and it actually seems to be ignoring my git files and apparently looking at some old SVN files that were left in there.  Voting to close question.